# iOS - Issue Creating Custom MKAnnotation Callout

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, ios9, mkannotation

Im having some issues styling my `MKAnnotation` callout bubble.  Originally I had a standard callout that consisted of just a title, subtitle and `leftCalloutAccessoryView`.  This created the following callout:

[image]

This worked fine until it was decided that the subtitle should also contain a series of five images that show the business's average ratting among user reviews.  This was done by creating a separate view and passing it as the `detailCalloutAccessoryView`.  This produced the following callout bubble:

[image]

For some reason when the view is passed to the `detailCalloutAccessoryView` the callout view is given a weird border around all UI components that create unwanted whitespace around the `leftCalloutAccessoryView` and between the title and subtitle.  How can I remove this white space?  I want the business's average ratting inside the subtitle and proper spacing between the title and `detailCalloutAccessoryView`.  How can this be achieved?  Is it possible to do so without creating the `callout` from scratch?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: no I was never able to solve this.

Comment: Can you share code and `UIView` which you have created for callout?

Answer (score 0):

Without code, it is hard to give a detailed answer.
But I found a hint that may solve your problem in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32897201/1987726):
Apparently, MapKit sets `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`, when you set a view to `detailCalloutAccessoryView`.
This means that you have to set auto layout constraints by your own.

Comment: @ScottOBot: Did you try to set auto layout constraints?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create one custom pin representing the Bubble (BubblePin), and each time the user selects one regular pin, you add the BubblePin at the same position of the last selected regular pin.
So adding one additional pin and switching its position according to the user selection will solve the problem, just make sure to add the BubblePin some offset so it won't be right on top of the regular one.