# Swift Annotation subtitle height and width

Tags: swift, dictionary, width, row, mkannotationview

My annotation looks like this now:
[image]

As you can see the text is too long for it to be showed. How can i make a new sentence below? Or just make the annotation subtitle wider so i can see all the text?

I want it to say "Antal personer: 5. Riktning öst: 4. Riktning väst: 1."

But the best would be:

"Antal personer: 5
Riktning öst: 4
Riktning väst: 1"

I have not been able to find any information on how to make a new row in subtitle. I have seen something with /n but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in iOS 9 we have a new property named `detailCalloutAccessoryView`

You can create a view and set as

```
annotationView.detailCalloutAccessoryView = tempView
```

Please check the link to get more details

[MapKit iOS 9 detailCalloutAccessoryView usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32581049/mapkit-ios-9-detailcalloutaccessoryview-usage)

Comment: I would follow this recommendation and make 'tempView' a `UITextView` as the default subtitle will go into to a `UILabel`. `UITextView` supports multiple lines and I'm sure you can find other answers on SO to show how to dynamically resize size of the `textView` based off text you have.

Comment: we can set the view size based on the length of the content . please check this link  it may help you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467/how-do-i-size-a-uitextview-to-its-content .